# Como faze site ser acessado com e sem "www"

Tags: apache, centos

meu site está acessando apenas sem o "www"
dentro do diretório do meu site, tem um .htaccess com essa regra:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdominio\.meusite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdominio\meusite\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/subdominio\meusite\.com\.br/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Eu uso o CentoS e Apache.
Será que tenho que ver alguma parada de módulo Rewrite se está ativo ou inativo no meu servidor?
Como eu faço isso?

E um outro problema, é que as minhas páginas só estão sendo acessadas com a extensão no final: .php, .html etc.. Como posso corrigir isso também?

Answer (score 2):

Para o problema das extensões verifique no arquivo de conf do seu apache o parâmetro `dir_module`, se não tiver adicione as seguintes linha:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

Reinicie o apache e teste, isso permite que os arquivos `index.html` ou `index.php` na pasta raiz do site dentro do apache serem aberto automaticamente para o usuário Ex: o que antes era acessado com `www.meusite.com.br/index.php` agora poderá ser acessado com `www.meusite.com.br`, os nomes index.html e index.php são comumente utilizados como padrão (se não for padrão para o seu caso adicione o nome do arquivo do diretório raiz do servidor apache que queira abrir).

Sobre o acesso do seu site precisar conter o `www` no inicio você vai precisar criar uma entrada `DNS`, se você utiliza o `Bind` como servidor DNS você deve ter a zona referente ao seu site criada, é bem provável que você tenha algo parecido com isso em seu servidor DNS.

```
zone "meusite.com.br" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/namedb/remote/meusite.com.br.zone";
};
```

vá até o arquivo `meusite.com.br.zone` e crie a entrada `www` para o seu site:

```
www            IN      A       XXX.XX.XX.XX (IP publico do seu servidor web)
```

Se este IP já tem algum nome cadastrado o que geralmente acontece crie uma entrada `CNAME`, Incremente o serial do arquivo de conf do DNS e reinicie o serviço do DNS para que sua entrada DNS possa se propagar ao redor do mundo.